# WPF ComboBox Master - Slave

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have 2 combobox master-slave in this way:

```
<ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding MySource}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" />
<ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding MySelectedItem.Items}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="{x:Null}" />
```

But when I select one item of first combobox which it has empty list of Items after I have selected one of them with Items and selected item in second combobox. The text in second combobox is not empty. I have tried with IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" too.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you rephrase better what you want? I did not understand well the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sur to understand what you are trying to say... But I am pretty sur that you didn't notify a PropertyChanged after modify your "MySelectedItem" and you forget the mode=TwoWay...

If you want to use the SelectedItem in your ViewModel:

Xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding MySource}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" />
<ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding MySelectedItem.Items}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private YourItemType _mySelectedItem;
public YourItemType MySelectedItem
{
 get { return (_mySelectedItem);}
set
{
if (_mySelectedItem != value)
{
 _mySelectedItem = value;
if (PropertyChanged != null)
   PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MySelectedItem"));
}
}
```

}

If you just want to do a filtering:

```
<ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding MySource}" DisplayMemberPath="Description" name="source"/>
<ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Items, ElementName=source}"/>
```

Comment: yes, SelectedItem is notifing propertychanged, and I have tried Mode=Twoway, but the problem continues. My steps are: Select item A in combo1, select item A1 in combo2, then select itemB in combo1. Then combo2 is empty, because item B has not childs, but combo2 shows itemA1 in its text

Comment: try to bind selectedIndex in the second combo, and set it to -1 when items.count==0

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, it was that I have associated a command with interactivity in the combobox and this was catching an exception and didn't continue with the execution.